# Why wont go print from thread after infinit go routine on Ubuntu

Tags: go

I have a go program that looks like this on Ubuntu

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    count := 2

    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {

        go  ping()
    }

    for  {}
}

func ping() {

    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second )
        fmt.Println("hello world")

    }
}
```

The idea was to call the go routine twice and then in each running of the go routine I would wait 1 seconds and then print `"hello world"` however the output from this program on ubuntu is no output. It seems to work on OSX

here is the output from OSX:

[image]

on Ubuntu the output looks like this

[image]

Is there a reason for this madness?
Am I doing something wrong that perhaps is being handled differently on two different Operating Systems?

Why does Ubuntu show no output?

Comment: Why was this down voted ? it is a legitimate questions

Comment: Just because something is a legitimate question doesn't make it into an interesting question or something valuable for other users.

Answer (score 3):

A busy-wait `for {}`-loop does not yield to the scheduler and so your goroutines might or might not be able to run. This has nothing to do with the OS; just get rid of the `for {}` loop.

Comment: Totally agree about the busy for loop, but getting rid of it as the code stands now will yield zero output on all platforms because the program will exit immediately before the goroutines have a chance to run.

Comment: @sberry Please excuse my sloppy expression. With "get rid of" I didn't mean "delete it entirely" but "replace with something which yields to the scheduler".

Comment: +1, but you should change the wording and perhaps give an example like a `waitGroup`, `runtime.Goexit()`, read from nil / empty channel, etc, etc.